# Materialize select dropdown is selectable even when dropdown is not visible

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu, materialize

I have implemented Materialize for a project. As can be seen in the image, even when dropdown is not active, if I hover in the vicinity of the dropdown, I can select an option. Not sure, how and why this is happening.

[image: Materialize dropdown is selectable]

HTML code below. The z-depth-1 class to fieldset doesn't affect the behavior mentioned.

Created a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ss3yd6jf/, but it doesn't show the behavior mentioned. I believe, it has to do with how materialize renders with and without options. No idea, what is happening here. If I select even one dropdown, the behavior goes away.

```
<div class="horizontal-list label-top filterTable main-div-shadow row section" id="filterTable" style="display:none">
<fieldset class="z-depth-1">
<legend><h4>{translate key=Filter}</h4></legend>
<div class="col s12">
    <form id="filterForm">
        <!-- <div class="main-div-header">{translate key=Filter}</div> -->
        <ul class="section">
            <li style="padding-left:0px !important">
                <label for="filterResourceName">{translate key=ResourceName}</label>
                <input type="text" id="filterResourceName" class="textbox" {formname key=RESOURCE_NAME} value="{$ResourceNameFilter}"/ />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="filterScheduleId">{translate key=Schedule}</label>
                <select id="filterScheduleId" {formname key=SCHEDULE_ID} class="textbox">
                    <option value="">{translate key=AllSchedules}</option>
                    {object_html_options options=$AllSchedules key='GetId' label="GetName" selected=$ScheduleIdFilter}
                </select>
            </li>

            <li>
                <label for="filterResourceType">{translate key=ResourceType}</label>
                <select id="filterResourceType" class="textbox" {formname key=RESOURCE_TYPE_ID}>
                    <option value="">{translate key=All}</option>
                    {object_html_options options=$ResourceTypes key='Id' label="Name" selected=$ResourceTypeFilter}
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="resourceStatusIdFilter">{translate key=ResourceStatus}</label>
                <select id="resourceStatusIdFilter" class="textbox" {formname key=RESOURCE_STATUS_ID}>
                    <option value="">{translate key=All}</option>
                    <option value="{ResourceStatus::AVAILABLE}">{translate key=Available}</option>
                    <option value="{ResourceStatus::UNAVAILABLE}">{translate key=Unavailable}</option>
                    <option value="{ResourceStatus::HIDDEN}">{translate key=Hidden}</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="resourceReasonIdFilter">{translate key=Reason}</label>
                <select id="resourceReasonIdFilter" class="textbox" {formname key=RESOURCE_STATUS_REASON_ID}>
                    <option value="">{translate key=None}</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="filterCapacity">{translate key=MinimumCapacity}</label>
                <input type="number" min="0" id="filterCapacity" class="textbox" {formname key=MAX_PARTICIPANTS} value="{$CapacityFilter}"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="filterRequiresApproval">{translate key='ResourceRequiresApproval'}</label>
                <select id="filterRequiresApproval" class="textbox" {formname key=REQUIRES_APPROVAL}>
                    {html_options options=$YesNoOptions selected=$RequiresApprovalFilter}
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="filterAutoAssign">{translate key='ResourcePermissionAutoGranted'}</label>
                <select id="filterAutoAssign" class="textbox" {formname key=AUTO_ASSIGN}>
                    {html_options options=$YesNoOptions selected=$AutoPermissionFilter}
                </select>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="filterAllowMultiDay">{translate key=ResourceAllowMultiDay}</label>
                <select id="filterAllowMultiDay" class="textbox" {formname key=ALLOW_MULTIDAY}>
                    {html_options options=$YesNoOptions selected=$AllowMultiDayFilter}
                </select>
            </li>
            {foreach from=$AttributeFilters item=attribute}
                <li class="customAttribute">
                    {control type="AttributeControl" attribute=$attribute searchmode=true idPrefix="search"}
                </li>
            {/foreach}
            <li>
                <div id="adminFilterButtons" class="right-align">
                    <button id="filter" class="button btn waves-effect waves-light"><i class="material-icons left">search</i> {translate key=Filter}</button>
                    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <a href="#" id="clearFilter" class="btn-flat waves-effect waves-light">{translate key=Reset}</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: add high z-index;

Comment: add some html code like jsfidle

Comment: can you create a fiddle or codepen

Comment: I created the jsfiddle @Naila